# Make WPF RichTextBox accept only text and Set maximum length

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to restrict the my RichTextBox will only accept plan text, i. e user cannot allow to paste the image in it.also want to set maximum number of character allow in RichTextBox.

How can i achieve this.?

Comment: just a quick question - is there a good reason for not just using a TextBox in this scenario? TextBox has a MaxLength property...

Comment: I need multiformatted support that user can set different font for different character font that reason i am using RichTextBox

Comment: For multiformatted font support ur using RichTextBox , so why do u need to restrict it for plain text alone ? Want plain text go for textbox otherwise go for richtext box.

Comment: The question has an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321385/how-to-make-richtextbox-text-only
And, by the way @Varatharaj it has its uses - sometimes you want formatted text without pictures in it.